# push items to array whose variable name is dynamic in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, dynamic, associative-array

i have the following 3 variables:

```
        private $a_total;
        private $b_total;
        private $c_total;
```

now when the fields are filled out with some data for totals, names of those fields are "a", "b", and "c". I want to store it dynamically to the variables above something like:

```
      $type = $_POST['totaltype']; //either a, b or c
      $to_save = "{$type}_total";
      $this->$to_save['total'] = some number;
```

if i try to

```
 print_r($this->$to_save);
```

it gives empty array. If i try to:

```
 print_r($this->$to_save['total']);
```

it gives correct number.

can anyone help?

Note: i want to use dynamically because these data will be inside a big loop so i don't want to reuse `$a_total`, `$b_total`, `$c_total` since i will have more than `a`, `b` and `c` variables.

Comment: It might be better to restructure the way you're accessing this. Have you considered `$this->totals[$type]`. There's no reason to dynamically create a variable for this case.

Comment: i need to store it in database as separate serialized array. will that work for the case?

Comment: Well yes, if you `serialise($this->totals)` you'll get an array with an associative structure. If you're using one of the below answers, go for it - just didn't immediately see why you'd need to incur the overhead of dynamically creating these variables.

Comment: this would work also but for this project i need it dynamic, thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the variable name in curly-brackets inside the class:

```
$this->{$type . "_total"} = 5;
```

The same works when accessing it like an array:

```
$this->{$type . "_total"}['total'] = 5;
```

You can also save the full-name of the variable in a string, such as your `$to_save` and access it the same way:

```
$to_string = $type . '_total';
$this->{$to_string}['total'] = 5;
print_r($this->{$to_string});
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for, curly-brackets did the trick thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change `$a_total` to `$total['a']`, `$b_total` to `$total['b']`, and `$c_total` to `$total['c']`,

Then you can access the values dynamically.